# What is the meaning of the log from tag:"szipinf" and text:"Initializing inflate state" from Logcat

Tags: android, logging, state, inflate, initializing

I am a new programmer for Android, so please excuse my knowledge and also my English because it is not my first language. So I am having a log with the tag:"szipinf" and text:"Initializing inflate state" and I don`t know what it means.... I also seen that it appears only when I test the game on my phone, on the emulator it doesn't show up. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what it means.

Answer (score 4):

Let's [search](http://androidxref.com/source/) this message through the source code to find who prints the log. `StreamingZipInflater.cpp`:

```
/*
 * Streaming access to compressed data held in an mmapped region of memory
 */
StreamingZipInflater::StreamingZipInflater(FileMap* dataMap, size_t uncompSize) {
    ...
    initInflateState();
}

void StreamingZipInflater::initInflateState() {
    LOGV("Initializing inflate state");
    ...
}
```

The next question we'd like to ask is [where](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/libs/utils/Asset.cpp) and how it's used? In the `_CompressedAsset` which is a subclass of `Asset` for dealing with compressed files:

```
/*
 * Instances of this class provide read-only operations on a byte stream.
 *
 * Access may be optimized for streaming, random, or whole buffer modes.  All
 * operations are supported regardless of how the file was opened, but some
 * things will be less efficient.
 *
 * "Asset" is the base class for all types of assets.  The classes below
 * provide most of the implementation.  The AssetManager uses one of the
 * static "create" functions defined here to create a new instance.
 */
```

More precisely:

```
static Asset* createFromCompressedFile(const char* fileName, AccessMode mode);
```

You can find usages of this class in renderscript, `BitmapFactory` and other places.